# Excel VBA: How to detect which control was clicked?

Tags: vba, excel, controls

My worksheet can dynamically add a series of ActiveX labels, named "lblLong1", "lblLong2", etc. as needed. When the user clicks a label, I want to take the text in the Caption and use it in a different macro.

The brute force method would be to write a Click event for every possible label, even the ones that don't currently exist. For example:

```
Private Sub lblLong3_Click()
    Dim t As String
    t = Me.lblLong3.Caption
    Call Macro1(t)
End Sub
```

I'm sure I could write 30 of these, but that can't be the best way, can it? Is there a better approach?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've explored this question several times over the years.  The shortest way to code this is to make a function call, passing the control caption that was clicked to a VBA sub or function.  You'll still have to have an event for each clickable control.

```
Private Sub lblLong3_Click()
    Call Macro1(Me.lblLong3.Caption)
End Sub

Private Sub Macro1(strCaption As String)
    ' Code To Execute
End Sub
```

The only way you might get around this is to use "Form.ActiveControl" with a timer event to identify the control with the focus.  Just put a flag in the routine so it only runs once unless the control with focus changes.  But watch out for the "Tab" button, because it could cause a lot of unintentional runs for the routine as focus changes.

You could have it check only the controls you wanted by using the "Tag" property.  Set it to "CheckMe" for each control you want checked, set the "tab" property to false for those same controls and use as follows.

```
Dim strLastCaption As String

Private Sub Form_Timer()
    If me.ActiveControl.Tag = "CheckMe" Then
        If Me.ActiveControl.Caption <> strLastCaption Then
            strLastCaption = Me.ActiveControl.Caption
            Call Macro1(strLastCaption)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It sounds like you're saying that what I had suggested is the only real way to do it. Is that correct?

Comment: Exactly.  Been through this on many occasions, trying the exact same thing your trying to do.  There isn't a shorter method to accomplish this.  The event is required in some way, no matter what avenue or angle you approach this from.  I really wanted there to be a way... but it just isn't going to happen.

Comment: Just added one method that might work, but it would be a handful on its own.

Comment: Code posted in modified answer that might help.

Comment: I've been doing some reading, and it seems that by using custom class modules and WithEvents -- two things I know nothing about -- can let you write Event code once and apply it to multiple controls. Here's an example on VBA Express: http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-31316.html